# How can white gain a slight advantage in this position? (puzzle for beginners)

Tags: beginner, puzzles

Try solving the following puzzle (for beginners), where it is white to move and gain a slight advantage, despite being a queen down for a bishop:

```
[FEN "2k1r3/pp6/n5q1/1N3p2/8/3B4/5PPP/5RK1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Not only drawing chances, but also starting a good fight for the win!

Comment: Yeah white is a pawn up after the trick

Comment: Thanks @David good point, I have edited the title and the content accordingly

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
[FEN "2k1r3/pp6/n5q1/1N3p2/8/3B4/5PPP/5RK1 w - - 0 1"]

1. Bxf5 Qxf5 2. Nd6
```

and a cute family fork wins the queen. White is up a pawn.

Comment: That's right, good one @12358

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that Black cannot refuse the bishop since it's forking the king and queen.